# primary keys are shifted

Tags: sql, database

### Background Information

For some reason, while inserting a huge data into multiple tables from xml, my primary keys are shifted by an offset.. (Maybe because of multiple failed attempts :P)

I have two tables.. tableA and tableB. They are in one-to-may relationship.
tableA is the parent table and has the Primary key column ...say DataIndex.

now DataIndex has come out like this..

> 685, 686, 687... and so on.

and corresponding values present in the child table i.e TableB are the same.

### Problem

**How do I shift the values up so that DataIndex start from 1, 2, 3..and so on; In both tables ?**

Comment: If you're in any way relying on the numerical values of an auto-generated column, you're doing something wrong. Why does it *matter* that they're up in the 600s? You should, ideally, treat the values in this column as opaque blobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the primary key is actually an identity column that auto-increments itself upon insertion. What you will need to do is 'reseed' the identity column. You can do this by renaming the table, create a duplicate table with the original name, then inserting the data from the old table to the new one (the primary key field will be reset and will auto-increment from 1 again). When doing the insertion, make sure to include the old primary key value as an additional column for reference in the other tables.

To match up the related table, all you will need to do is do an `UPDATE` and join to your new table on the old primary key value:

```
UPDATE tableB SET
   PRIMARYKEYCOLUMN = tableA.PRIMARYKEYCOLUMN
FROM tableA
WHERE
   tableA.OLDPRIMARYKEYCOLUMN = tableB.PRIMARYKEYCOLUMN
```

Comment: And what about related table?

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove PK
2. Walk through records eith DB CURSOR or write a script on any language sequentally reading and changing id's
3. Restore PK
4. Setup correct identity seed for the PK

Changing seed might involve identity column drop and recreate.

Comment: by "manually" i mean use database cursor or small script on any language.  What DB engine are you using?

Comment: MS-SQL. can you help me with that script ?

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

1. construct a list of Foreign Keys pointing to your PK;
2. `ALTER` all FKs, adding `ON UPDATE CASCADE` clause. This step might not work for some databases, you might need to `DROP` and `CREATE` constraint again;
3. Find the smallest current PK values, like: `SELECT min(id) FROM tableA;`
4. Refresh PK values: `UPDATE tableA SET id = id - min_id + 1;`
5. Remove `ON UPDATE CASCADE` clause.

Note, that depending on the `tableA` size and the database engine you're using, it might be faster and easier to completely rebuild the table to avoid bloat of data files.